# How to find the ascii code to a given letter, if the binay code for another letter is given?

Tags: binary, ascii

How do I answer this question?
If the character "A" is represented by 1000001 in the ASCII system, what is the ASCII code for the letter "F"?

How do I get the answer for this without looking at the table?

Answer (score 1):

In ASCII the capital letters are assigned consecutive character codes. So if you know that the character code for the first capital letter, A, is 65, then you can deduce that the character code for the sixth capital letter, F, is 65 + 5 = 70.